# date renderer issue in extjs

Tags: extjs

I have a date renderer issue for a column. When browser language is in English the date is displayed in this format

```
09/14/2009 09:23 AM
```

But when I change the browser language to German(displays correctly in English and French) the date is not rendered it displays `NAN/NAN/NAN 12:NAN PM`

Here is the code.

```
var dateRenderer = Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y h:i A');

var colModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
{ 
     header: xppo.st('SDE_DATE_OCCURRED'), 
     width: 75, 
     sortable: true, 
     dataIndex: 'DateOccurred', 
     renderer: dateRenderer 
}]);
```

How can I render the date in other languages? Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that the input date is being parsed correctly for German?  The dateRenderer output should be the same -- if it works at all, the language should not matter.  Since you are getting NaN it's more likely that something in the input data for German is invalid.

Comment: The data on server side is rendered correctly..

German: on the server side thwe date rendered in german is in this format 14.09.2009 10:23:00 and on the client side it displays NAN/NAN/NAN 12:NAN PM For french on the server side the date rendered on server is in this format 14/09/2009 10:23:00 and on client side it displays 14/09/2009 10:23 AM

Comment: var dateRenderer = Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y h:i A');
Date renderer in german is m.d.Y and not m/d/Y Can you please help me how do i display date rendere in german correctly?

Comment: If I dont use any rendere for that column then the data is displayed as 14.09.2009 10:23:00 but when i use date rendere in that column it is displayed as NAN. Can you please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use an Ext.grid.DateColumn ? its very simple...
simply pass

```
format: "d.m.Y H:i:s"
```

to its constructor and everything should be fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. But it was fixed only when correct **dateFormat** was set.
*(Of course data must be passed from server side correctly)*

```
reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        root: 'mails',
        totalProperty: 'totalCount',
        idProperty: 'mail_id',
        fields: [
            'mail_id',
            {name: 'mail_date', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'Y-m-d h:i:s'}
        ]
}
```

...

```
this.columns = [sm,{
    header: 'Date',
    dataIndex: 'mail_date',
    width: 150,
    renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d.m.Y H:i:s'),
    sortable: true
}];
```